# Selection to code syntax on ipad

Tags: feature-request, editor

It's nearly impossible to use the editor's toolbar on an iPad, in case you have a selection on the first line text inside the editor. You cannot reach the buttons below anymore. It's hard to explain, but take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

Currently I add some extra newlines before the first line of text, then hit the bold, link, code or image button, and then remove the newlines. Since typing on a iPad already sucks, I'd love to see a workaround for this.

Comment: I wonder if solving this will really make everyone that much more productive on the iPad. This is the tip of the iceberg, and it's mostly the iPad's fault, not the network's.

Comment: No, it's not the network's fault, but I'd love to see it fixed, that's why I tagged it as feature-request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solution to this would be to place the toolbar stuff on the side … which would actually be useful off the iPad as well when the question or answer box gets really big.  if the tools were placed in a javascript floating sidebar of some sort once the text-box for the question or answer is active, then they'd always be handy without scrolling.

Comment: Well I guess that would be worse, since it now only affects the first 2 lines, then it would affect lot's of lines, since the iPad-toolbar also floats to the left.

Comment: no, i'm talking about over in the left whitespace, it would be to the left of and below the iPad stuff shown above, and it would be to the left of all text.  i don't think he's concerned about temporarily covering up text.  he's concerned about being able to click on the buttons behind what's hidden at the moment.